# How to put data from a file in to javascript array

Tags: javascript

I give user an option to choose a dataset. Currently I have a dataset with 14 columns and I give an option to user to choose two dimensions out of it .

How do I load this data selected by user in to a javascript array so that my javascript apps can read it ???

any suggestions ??

thanks :)

Comment: This question is extremely vague. What format is the data in? What is the data source? Where is the data located? How are you providing the data and in what programming language is it being formatted and served?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your implementation, I can only answer with very vague generalities.  I will first assume that you are not actually trying to get data from a "file" to javascript, but that you mean from a "script" to javascript.

I will also assume that you already have the data you're after in some kind of an array.  Since you did not specify the server-side language, I will assume PHP:

```
// sample data array
$the_data = array(
 'color'=>'red',
 'type'=>'apple'
);
print json_encode($the_data);
```

The preceding code illustrates conversion from a server-side data type to a string which can be parsed and thus converted to a client-side object.  On the client side, you will need to use some kind of method to convert this json encoded string to an object.  Using the vanilla JSON object:

```
JSON.decode(responseText);
```

Your question leaves many details to assume.  If you clarify your question, I can provide a much more specific answer.  Otherwise/until then, I hope this helps.  :)